How to customize the url structure?
The problem is complex. When ACF and YAST SEO are activated, and custom taxonomy does not have a slug, the code is below. However, regular pages display a 404 error. I tested it on pure WordPress. ACF purchased, latest version.
register_taxonomy(
'course_cats',
'course',
 array(
 'hierarchical'      => true,
 'show_admin_column' => true,
 'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
 'labels'            =>array(),
 'query_var'         => true,
 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false),
 'show_in_rest' => true,
    )
  );


The problem is your slug parameter, it can't just be / - you need to have something that identifies the URL as being this taxonomy. It defaults to the taxonomy key which in this case would be course_cat but in the interest of human-readable URLS you could do this instead:
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'course-category', 'with_front' => false )


How about the Remove Taxonomy URL plugin? Is it even possible to remove a URL? When I use ACF and remove the taxonomy URL, other pages get 404 errors, but if ACF is is turned off, everything works.  Maybe there is some way to remove the bullet and make it work?

If you don't want the taxonomy to have an archive page all you need to do is pass it publicly_queryable => false

i want remove taxonomy slug from url. why did you write about archive page?

You asked if it was possible to remove a URL. I assumed you were talking about the taxonomy archive. Could you explain in a little more detail what you're trying to do with the URLs and why?
